# Adding menus to custom window chrome

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

I have basically read all of the questions posted about the custom window chrome and I have come along a few libraries as well.

Still I don't know what is the best solution for what I want to achieve. I want to remove the default chrome in `.NET4` and I also want to be able to add menus to the replace custom chrome. I want something like the `Photoshop CS6` chrome and I also want it to look well on `Windows XP`. What is the best approach/library for me?

[image]

Comment: You say you saw a lot of questions and libraries... have you actually tried to implement any of them?

Comment: Yes I'm lost which one is the best one and that actually works on XP. Because at the moment I don't have access to XP.

Comment: I see... well, "best" is highly subjective (I created my own custom window chrome and it works well for me). Can't help you with Windows XP, I'm afraid...

Comment: @vesan Were you able to add menus etc?

Comment: Well, I just have buttons, but the chrome is nothing more than a `Grid`, so I can add whatever I want. It's nothing special, really, if you just google for "WPF custom window", you'll get thousands of articles doing exactly the same thing I'm doing...

Comment: @vesan Thanks, I'll try again. Can you point me the one you said that actually uses Grids?

Comment: For example this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library

Comment: @vesan Actually I have downloaded this. But then I saw that it hasn't changed the `Border` of the window.

Comment: It seems actually I can change the border too.